# adding input file tag programmatically using js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add input (type file) field to my html using js. I've got it done, but the problem is when the user chooses a file then clicks on the "new file" button to choose another one, The prevoius choosen file goes away and says no file chosen. what is the problem?

```js
function newfile(){
    var divv=document.getElementById("files");
    var name="files"+divv.childNodes.length;
    divv.innerHTML+='<div><input id="'+name+'" name="'+name+'" type="file" accept="*" class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-6"></div>';
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div id="files"></div>
<a class="btn btn-primary col-sx-12" onclick="newfile()">New file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use appendChild() instead of innerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because everytime you use `divv.innerHTML+='<div><input id="'+name+'" name="'+name+'" type="file" accept="*" class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-6"></div>'` all contents in divv are replaced with new contents and the previous information is lost.
you can use `appendChild()` here, something like this:

```js
function newfile(){
var divv=document.getElementById("files");
var name="files"+divv.childNodes.length;
var inputNode = document.createElement("input");
inputNode.id = name;
inputNode.name = name;
inputNode.type = 'file';
divv.appendChild(inputNode);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div id="files"></div>
<a class="btn btn-primary col-sx-12" onclick="newfile()">New file</a>
</div>
```